# maven command to copy dependencies into eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, lib

Is there a maven run command to copy maven dependencies (jars) into an eclipse project folder (like src/libraries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 (this works)